# How to programmatically return back to home in autodesk forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have a viewer where I zoom in and focus on an object by it's dbID with the following script.

```
viewer.fitToView([dbId]);
let color = new THREE.Vector4(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5);
window.viewer.setThemingColor(item.link,color)
```

I can clear the theming colors with clearThemingColors() call. But for now, I use the home icon at the top to return to the home position. Is there a way to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewer.utilities.goHome();`

Ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewingutilities/#gohome